# dynamic function call parameters

Tags: php, callback, frameworks, arguments

Today I have used a Klein Semi Framework and I wanted to understand something which is really important for me to know.

```
$klein->respond('/report/latest', function ($request, $response, $service) {
     $response->file('/tmp/cached_report.zip');
});
```

for example in this code we pass into the function three variables request, response and service. How does it know to put into the request variable the request class, to put into the response variable the response class, etc. no matter the order of the varaibles?

Is there any example of code that will help me to understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: In the future, please try and tag accordingly. You never know if the related tag (for this particular framework) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the framework, but based on your explanation, I'd assume they are using reflection to get the name and order of the parameters you provided to the closure.  You can see an example of this here:  (https://3v4l.org/jjWa1)

```
$closure = function ($request, $response, $service) {
     $response->file('/tmp/cached_report.zip');
};

$reflected = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
var_dump($reflected->getParameters());
```

ReflectionFunction allows you to get details about a function's definition.

Comment: I checked, They don't use it. The name of the Semi Framework is Klein.

Comment: If you're talking about https://github.com/klein/klein.php, I don't see anywhere that they allow different order of $request, $response, and $service.  They pass them in that order, you can't change them around.  You can review  [Klein::handleRouteCallback](https://github.com/klein/klein.php/blob/master/src/Klein/Klein.php) yourself.

Comment: Do you mean here? http://prntscr.com/kldxts It shows that he has to pass 8 variables but he passed only 3-4. it won't give him an error? Thanks!

Comment: It's the opposite, they are passing 8 variables, you only defined it with 3, so it will ignore the rest.  If you want  to define the rest, you can make use of those in the closure, but you don't need to define them all.  They still need to be in the correct order.

Comment: Oh I got you man. really thanks. I sent you the correct lines which do it right?

Comment: Yes you did.  Call_user_func is a common way to call an anonymous function.

Comment: Oh, Huge thanks. Great to know that you can mention variables there that will be optional and if you'll need them you will just mention them.

Answer (score 0):

`$request`, `$response`, and `$service` aren't variables in your current scope that you're passing into that function.

```
function ($request, $response, $service) { $response->file('/tmp/cached_report.zip'); }
```

Is an anonymous function, a callback that you're passing as the second argument to `$respond`. So the parameters for that function aren't defined at the time you call `$klein->respond()`. What you're doing there is creating a route by assigning that callback to the `$klein` object to handle the `'/report/latest'` route.

The idea of a router class like that is that you define functions to handle requests matching various routes, and when a route is matched, the router object will call the function you've defined for it and supply the necessary arguments to it at that time.

I'm not sure what you mean by "no matter the order of the variables". I think the callback needs to have those variables defined in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks! I got you!